# Create a new column that starts counting from 0 until the value in another column changes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe df that looks like this:

| ID | Months | Borrow_Rank |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 0 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 | 2 |
| 4 | 0 | 1 |
| 4 | 1 | 1 |

I want to create a new variable Months_Adjusted that starts counting from 0 for as long as Borrow_Rank remains the same.

| ID | Months | Borrow_Rank | Months_Adjusted |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 0 | 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 4 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 | 5 |
| 3 | 0 | 2 | 0 |
| 3 | 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 4 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 4 | 1 | 1 | 1 |

Thank you all and I apologise if I could have written the question better. This is my first post.

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Borrow_Rank':[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,1,1,1]})
selector = (df['Borrow_Rank'] != df['Borrow_Rank'].shift()).cumsum()
df['Months_Adjusted'] = df.groupby(selector).cumcount()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using `itertools.groupby` -

```py
from itertools import groupby
df['Months_Adjusted'] = pd.concat(
          [pd.Series(range(len(list(g)))) 
           for k, g in groupby(df['Borrow_Rank'])],
ignore_index=True)
```

**Output**

```
   ID  Months  Borrow_Rank  Months_Adjusted
0   1       0            1                0
1   1       1            1                1
2   1       2            1                2
3   2       0            1                3
4   2       1            1                4
5   2       2            1                5
6   3       0            2                0
7   3       1            2                1
8   4       0            1                0
9   4       1            1                1
```